# This formula count the number of times a value appears in different cells, but not within the same comma-seperated cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=(LEN(","&T2&",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(","&T2&",",","&$C$2&",",",")))/(1+LEN($C$2))
```

I'm trying to find how many times a value from 'C2' appears in a comma-separated list in cell 'T2'. ("1,2,3,4")

So far, the formula above counts that 'A3' appears in the cell once, and ignores the other comma-separated instances.

Any input appreciated.

For example,

Cell C2 would have the value of 3.413, ad cell T2 would have the value 13.413,13.413.

Currently, it is producing a count of 0.

Comment: Can you mock up some data and expected output.  That is the standard formula to do what you want, so we need some specific examples of the data to test why it is not working for you.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I cant see why it isn't working.

Cell C2 would have the value of 3.413, and cell T2 would have the value 13.413,13.413

This formula would go in U2 and produce a count of 2

Right now, its producing a count of 1.

Comment: so you want to count when it is partial?  So the count would be 2?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yessir

Comment: You need to remove all the `","` from your formula, by adding those it looks for complete matches: `13.413`<> `3.413`

Comment: `=(LEN(T2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(T2,$C$2,"")))/(1+LEN($C$2))`

Comment: @ScottCraner This seems to work now, instead of 2, it gives me 1.71, but that still works for what im trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: remove the `1+`: `=(LEN(T2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(T2,$C$2,"")))/(LEN($C$2))`

Answer (score 1):

When one book ends the values in the formula with the divider, `","` in this case.  It forces the formula to find exact replacements.

So we remove all the refrences to the `","` and the `1+` because we no longer care about the divider:

```
=(LEN(T2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(T2,$C$2,"")))/(LEN($C$2))
```

[image]